# How to handle authentication error, when starting SignalR connection from .NET client?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr.client

My client application connects to hub, that requires authentication (it's basic one + HTTPS).

When user enters wrong user name and password in application parameters, I want to handle connection error and show him a popup message. I thought, that handling `HubConnection.Error` event is a right way to go:

```
connection = new HubConnection($"{BaseAddress}/signalr");
connection.Error += Connection_Error;
```

but looks like I'm wrong: I can see thrown exceptions in VS output window, when this line executes:

```
await connection.Start().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

but `Connection_Error` never gets called.

Is there another way to detect that problem is in credentials?